# SignalR not working once I added Redirect

Tags: asp.net, signalr

Inside the **Page_Load** event of a website **default.aspx?token=xxxx**, I am able to generate a username.

If the url contains "token", then I will add this username as a query string and redirect to the same page.

```
Response.Redirect(@"~/default.aspx/?auth=" + username);
```

The moment i add this line SignalR does not seem to fire the onconnect event which simply increases a counter by 1 and displays it.

```
public static int count = 0;
        public override Task OnConnected()
        {
            count++;

            this.Clients.All.updateCounter(count);
            return base.OnConnected();
        }
```

---

```
    <div id="counter" style="font-size:40px;"></div>
-------------------------------------------------------------
$(function () {

                var hubProxy = $.connection.chatLobbyHub;
                hubProxy.client.updateCounter = function (count) {
                    $("#counter").text(count);
                };

                $.connection.hub.start();
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is because the hub is started twice in a very short period of time.

In my case, my signalr client is in the index.html, which may be located in the iis, or in an Android phone app, or in an iPhone app.  I found that with different phones, may be due to connection problem, sometimes the onconnected fired twice, or ondisconnected fired twice, or something that should be fired are not fired, anything can happen!

so my 'start hub JavaScript' is done via a JavaScript set time interval function, this 'timer' checks the connection status with the signalr Server, if the connection lost, I'll start the hub again.

after doing this, if the user open the index.html, then I even turn off the signalr Server, a few minutes later I turn on the Server again, then after a few seconds, everything restore to normal.